# Make buttons disappear due to user roles (kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to make a button disappear in my app when a user is a viewer? I have 3 types of users (viewer, editor and admin) and I want the same layout for the 3 of them but, the viewer cannot have access to some buttons. Is it possible to make the buttons disappear or should I make the exact same layouts but without the buttons? Thanks!

**edit**
here's a screenshot of firebase database
[image]

Comment: How do you define roles? Are you using custom claims or storing the roles in database? If database,  can you please share a screenshot of database structure?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, have you tried it? Share some code

Comment: @Dharmaraj I shared the screenshot in the post!

Comment: @peprumo I tried on " override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)" do "if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid == "Viewer"){
                  newDashButton.visibility = View.GONE
        }"

Answer (score 1):

The roles are stored in realtime database so you would have to first read that and then hide the buttons based on the role. Right now you are comparing the UID of user with the role "Viewer" - `if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid == "Viewer")`

```kotlin
val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser
val uid = user.uid

mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).child("Role").get().addOnSuccessListener {
    Log.i("firebase", "Got role ${it.value}")
    if (it.value == "Viewer") {
        newDashButton.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}.addOnFailureListener{
    Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", it)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it later and then I'll let you know!!